# As (Much) Instructive As Humorous

Tags: meaning, difference, adverbs, intensifiers

I have a question about the following sentence (from page 174 of the book "Influence: The Psychology of Persuasion" by Robert Cialdini):

1. "Although designed for a laugh, the remark is as ***much*** instructive as humorous."

How is the meaning changed if ***much*** is deleted?   In another word, how is "as **much** instructive as humorous" different from "as instructive as humorous"?

Added Section:

Suppose I then write the following sentence:

2. To us, he is as ***much*** a friend as a colleague.

Sentence 2 uses ***much*** in the "**to what extent**" sense.
Could it be that sentence 1 also uses ***much*** in the "**to what extent**" sense, instead of the "**very**" sense?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning isn't essentially changed—but *much*, like *very*, acts as an intensifier.

> Your gift is appreciated.
>   Your gift is *much* appreciated.

The second sentence expresses a higher level of gratitude.

---

Strangely, although I find the use of both *much instructive* and *much humorous* on their own to be ungrammatical, the use of *as much instructive as humorous* sounds fine to to me.

(And, equally strange, *as very instructive as humorous* also sounds wrong.)

So, the use of *as much* here may be the author's attempt to say that the remark is both *very* instructive and (equally) *very* humorous.

---

Having said all of that, I doubt anybody would notice the difference if *much* were removed.

Comment: I edited the original question.  I would appreciate it if you could offer some comments on it.

Comment: @meatie The second sentence could be analyzed and used in the same way as the first sentence. With its particular noun (*friend*), a different construction of *much* would need to be used in order for it to be thought of as an intensifier, but it is still possible: *She was not much of a friend*. The positive version is still grammatical, even if it's not idiomatic: *She was much of a friend.* However, the same analysis applies. (It would be very unusual for somebody to say that sentence and mean that somebody was a *bad* friend and equally *bad* colleague—instead they would use *as little*.)